# How can i get the path and host a url using regexp in postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
select 
regexp_substr(uri, 'http://([^/]*)') as domainname,
regexp_substr(uri, '[^"http://[a-zA-Z0-9]*"].*') as path, 
uri from http where uri;
```

Here is what I have tried already. But the path is not working. (host is not fool proof, but for my test that enough.

PS : as for the path its enough to have content upto last /, no need to go upto ? mark.

Edit : Example

Given a Url like following :
http://assets.adobedtm.com/a/b/c/041.js

I like to get the

- host : http://assets.adobedtm.com
- path : a/b/c

Comment: That SQL statement is buggy --- either `uri` is a string or a boolean, but not both. Please provide more detail what you need, including a clear question and maybe a sample for illustration.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe, I updated it with an example

Comment: I think you tried to use `'^(?!http://[a-zA-Z0-9]*).*'` (it will match any string other than those that start with `http://[a-zA-Z0-9]*` pattern)
. I am not sure you can use negative lookaheads in your environments though. At any rate, `[^"http://[a-zA-Z0-9]*"]` is a character class matching any 1 single char other than `"`, `h`, `t`, etc., and it does not seem it will ever work as you expect

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x[1] AS host, x[2] AS path
FROM (SELECT regexp_matches(
                'http://assets.adobedtm.com/a/b/c/041.js',
                '^(\w*://[^/]*)/(.*)/[^/]*$')
     ) x(x);

            host            | path
----------------------------+-------
 http://assets.adobedtm.com | a/b/c
(1 row)
```